# Trigger AWS Codebuild build subject to a folder change

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, git, github, aws-codebuild

I am hosting my application on github and I would like to perform builds with AWS Codubuild.
I have a lot of folders in my repo (can reach 400 folders), change in each folder should trigger it's own unique build. This can be done using webhooks I think but the problem is that I do not want to have 400 builds for each folder.

I was thinking of writing a script that checks for the changes in the repo using git diff and run a relevant build, however git diff seem to be checking the latest change in the repo and this will be the same code as the one that got downloaded by codebuild container and hence always getting no changes.What is the best way I can achieve this?